# Laravel sanctum custom model

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I'm using Laravel sanctum to authenticate my API, and I wanted to customize personal access token model so I did the following:

- I created new model named PersonalAccessToken in App namespace.
- I override model used in sanctum to be my new model by adding this line to my AppServiceProvider boot() method.

  Sanctum::usePersonalAccessTokenModel(PersonalAccessToken::class);

but when I create a token it works fine and insert it into DB but this line throw exception

```
return new NewAccessToken($token, $token->id.'|'.$plainTextToken);
```

and that's because it's type hinted to be an instance of Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken

how can I fix that

Answer (score 2):

If you are not extending the default **PersonalAccessToken** that maybe your issue.

Instead of extending **Model** extend **use Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken**

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken as Model;

class CustomPersonalAccessToken extends Model
{
     // Add you customisation here
}
```